# How to browse to Vagrant VM site from other devices on local network?

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, homestead, vagrant-windows

I'm running Laravel Homestead (Vagrant) on Windows 10.

**I'd like to be able to use other devices on my LAN to test my Homestead site too.** (My LAN also has a Mac and an iPhone.)

I found two ancient questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689014/access-private-vm-from-other-computer-over-wifi) and [2](https://serverfault.com/questions/545413/expose-virtual-machine-vagrant-to-local-wifi)) that seem related to my goal, but I'm still stuck.

I've tried adding a `public_network` config to my `Homestead.yaml` according to the docs (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead#network-interfaces).

I've tried editing the `homestead.rb` file directly, too (but that didn't seem to help, so I reverted it).

My `Homestead.yaml` is:

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa2013

folders:
    - map: c:/code/katievb-members
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/katievb-members

sites:
    - map: kvbmem.rcw
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/katievb-members/public
      schedule: false

databases:
    - kvbmem

networks:
    - type: "public_network"
      ip: "192.168.1.104"
      bridge: "Realtek RTL8811 Wireless LAN 802.11ac USB 2 Network Adapter"
```

My Windows machine is `192.168.1.104` on my LAN.

What should I change about my setup so that my Homestead website is browsable not just from the Windows machine that its on but also the other devices on the LAN?

And then what commands should I run before trying to browse to that site (`http://kvbmem.rcw`) on my iPhone? `vagrant reload --provision`?

(I have a DD-WRT router with DNSmasq if that will be helpful.)

Comment: you should not give the IP of your windows machine, but your VM should have their unique IP otherwise you will hit your windows server

Comment: @FrédéricHenri You sound like you know how to do what I'm hoping for, but I'm not sure what your recommendation is. What are you saying I should try? Remove the `ip` line? Or change it to what? Thanks!

Comment: Changing to `ip: "192.168.10.10"` didn't work either.

Comment: Can you try 192.168.1.100 for example

Comment: Thank you!!!! You could write this as an answer and I'd accept it because everything seems to be working now. I changed `ip: "192.168.1.104"` in the above config to `ip: "192.168.1.100"` and then in my DD-WRT "Additional DNSMasq Options" wrote `address=/kvbmem.rcw/192.168.1.100`. My iPhone and Windows PC both see http://kvbmem.rcw now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you pointed gave you good hints so you need to enable bridge connection, in vagrant its `public_network`

If you want to assign a static IP, you cannot use the same IP of your windows machine, otherwise the other machine from your LAN will hit the servers running on the windows machine.

You want to select an IP reachable on your LAN in the same network of your windows machine so if your current IP is `192.168.1.104` you can use any of the 192.168.1.x that is available, for example

```
networks:
    - type: "public_network"
      ip: "192.168.1.100"
      bridge: "Realtek RTL8811 Wireless LAN 802.11ac USB 2 Network Adapter"
```